# Concatenating XML files runs out of storage space

Tags: xml, ksh, informatica

My assignment is to concatenate several thousands XML files into one single file. The goal is to make loading 70,000+ files with Informatica ETL software  easier to load and maintain.

My XML files look like this

```
<insert_list><test_event_insert  endTime="2013-07-18T15:56:28" startTime="2013-07-18T07:35:11" operator="X-CLARKS1">.........</test_event_insert></insert_list>
```

I need to load in my database all the data between the "test_event_insert " tags so I created a KSH script script to grab the tags for each XML file and concatenate the data into one single file. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

#navigate to XML repository
cd $data

#some files have spaces in their names so it takes care of it here
find . -name '* *' | while read file
do
        target=`echo "$file" | sed 's/ /_/g'`
        echo "Renaming '$file' to '$target'"
        mv "$file" "$target"
done

#create MEGA file header
echo -e '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<insert_list>\n'>>$data/OUT.XML

#this is where I parse all my XMLs and create one MEGA file
for i in `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*XML"`
do
        sed 's:^<insert_list>\(.*\)</insert_list>$:\1:' "$i" ; echo -e "\n"
done>>$data/OUT.XML

#create MEGA file footer
echo -e '</insert_list>'>>$data/OUT.XML
```

It works great with 2,3 files. When I test it with 30,000 files, the script seems to get stuck in a loop and my output file outgrows my file system (3GB: small server).

What am I doing wrong here? I am not sure where the bug is in my script...any idea?

Comment: your quickest road to understanding is to add more debugging information. Right now, we have no idea how big your files are, and if the growth in size matches the file sizes you are adding together. Something like `wc $i $data/OUT.XML`, make sure the numbers make sense. AND Your echo of the header to the file should probably be with 1 `>` char and not 2. Also, I would  write the output to a different dir than your `$data` dir. You could be reloading your OUT.XML into itself. Good luck.

Comment: Did you consider using an indirect source file? Instead of merging the XML files, you'll only need to create a file containing their names (and paths if they're in different folders).

Comment: Have you tried to move the redirection `>>$data/OUT.XML` inside the loop? This way you would close the output file (repeatedly) after each input file. Also, does the input files and the output file reside in the same directory? This may be a bad idea since the file pattern for your input files matches the name of your output file. :-)

Comment: Well, this is embarassing...shellter and Marcus were correct. I was reloading my OUT.XML into itself. This has been fixed.